# How can I stop wobbling after installing a table saw blade

Tags: table-saw

Every time I install my table saw blade it is a little wobbly, is there a proper way to install a blade? Should I have the table saw on it's side and put it on? What am I doing wrong.

The saw is a [Rockwell Shop Series 10" Table Saw](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CJLUXI).

Comment: Have you checked that your blade arbor is clean? If so, and if you are tightening the nut properly, and the blade itself isn't bent, I'd worry about a bend in the saw's drive shaft. Or worn-out bearings.

Comment: You can correct for wobble using shims, if you've ruled out all the other culprits.  Sometimes cheaper saws just don't have the fit and finish and need a little tweaking.

Comment: Please tell us a little more.  Is it a cabinet or portable tablesaw?  New or old? Maybe make and model?  How much does it wobble (approx.).  Does the blade lie flat on the table surface when removed?

Comment: I own the Rockwell® Shopseries™ 10" Table Saw. It was in my budgit... new. recent model, a good amount... the wood vibrates across the top... even with the old blade in

Comment: Have you seen the video and info from Matthias Wandel on arbor runout?  [Check this page and video.](https://www.woodgears.ca/saw_arbor/index.html)  Its pretty well done.  Note a dial indicator doesn't cost a lot of money...

Comment: Yes, that video was very, very helpful and I did find some of those problems and they are fixed. I can not say thank you enough!

Comment: @zipzit, sounds like you should post that as an answer so OP can upvote & check the mark. Give you a few more magical interwebz points & be easier to find for others who may have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the fabrication or assembly of the saw so there may not be a correct answer.  I am concerned that the saw may not be safe so I am answering this with a few recommendations on how to verify it's safety.

Reviews of the saw on sites like Amazon are not very complementary.  If you can return it I would consider doing so.  If not...

- Check the blade for flatness.  If you lay it on its side on a flat surface does it lie flat all around?  Try using another blade in the saw to see if it wobbles the same way.
- Check the mountings of the motor to the housing to make sure everything is secure. Tighten up everything you can.
- Rotate the shaft (unplugged) to see if it is bent.  If it is then the shaft must be replaced.  I can't tell from the manual whether this requires a new motor or not.
- If the wobble is slight, try shimming the blade as [suggested by grfrazee in his comment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/installing-a-table-saw-blade#comment7713_3795). I'm not sure how this is done so you might ask another question to get more info.

Comment: _Check the blade for flatness._ Depeding on tolerance for flat you would have an issue if the teeth were larger than the blade. Resting a ruler across gullets would compliment findings well.

Comment: Okay, so I need to check the teeth then? Because they might be different sizes all round?